# How do I tell solr where my document collection is?

Tags: solr

My sysadmin installed [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) here: `/software/packages/solr-4.3.1/` I followed the [tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_3_1/tutorial.html) (using Jetty) successfully. We have a working installation and things work as expected.  I also, using [Solarium](http://www.solarium-project.org/), can query the example/collection1 document set from my website.

Now I want to create my own document set that will live outsite of `/software/packages/solr-4.3.1/` but still use the instance of solr that lives in `/software/packages/solr-4.3.1/`. I copied over the example directory to `/path/to/mydocs`. I tried to go through the tutorial again from the new location. No dice. How do I tell solr where my document collection is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're running in `multicore` mode (where a single Solr service can host multiple cores/indexes), I would assume you'd use your `solr.xml` file to store the relative `instanceDir` path.

So the `<core>` element would be something like:

```
<core name="MyCore" instanceDir="/path/to/mydocs" />
```

This would place the data and config files in your specified directory